# Setting Static IP with Predictable network interface

Tags: linux, kali-linux, network-interface

So i am currently facing a problem booting my 2016.2 Kali linux:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

I have set a static ip addressing in `/etc/network/interfaces` file 
by writing:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inter static 
address x.x.x.x
netmask x.x.x.x
gateway x.x.x.x
```

according to this source:[source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)
there is some problem with predictable network interface names, I couldn't really understand what really is the problem, but I wanted to use my eth0 interface name so adding `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules` file with the following: 
`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", NAME="eth0"` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes) by **JonnyTischbein** but with no success.

Could you please provide me with a good explanation about the predictable interfaces name problem, and what is the solution I should do in my cause?

are the lines in the `/etc/network/interfaces` files causing this problem?

Comment: Did you correct the MAC address (`ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`) and interface name (`eth0`) as mentioned on that page?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Yes, of course I did :)

Comment: Note there may be a typo in your file: `inter` should be `inet` I think?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please provide me with a good explanation about the predictable interfaces name problem, and what is the solution I should do in my cause?

Predictable interface names isn't a *problem*, it's a *solution* to a problem. If you have multiple Ethernet interfaces, in some cases, it won't be guaranteed that `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`, etc, will be the *same* interfaces after a reboot. At the next boot, the kernel might detect your USB ethernet adapters in a different order reversing `eth1` and `eth2`.

So the new naming encodes the path to the interface in hardware (such as the PCI slot number). And when detection order is not reasonably fixed, such as in the case of USB adapters, the MAC address is included in the interface name for complete disambiguation.

So, just leave out your custom `udev` rule and deal with a predictable interface name like `ens1` rather than `eth0`. Enjoy your tux!

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, now it's clear to me, but could you please provide with a further explanation on how would i use ens1 instead of eth0 (what changes should I make?), plus I don't really understand how to choose a predictable name (or is it automated?)