# Startup Debian 9 error: `Failed to start Raise network interfaces`

Tags: debian, networking, systemd

On a fresh installation of `Debian 9 Stretch` on a desktop PC when booting the

```
...
Failed to start Raise network interfaces
...
```

error occurres. The (cable) LAN-connection works but the (USB) WiFi is not working properly (detecting the WiFi networks but failing to connect). Previously on the same harware `Debian 8 Jessie` was installed working fine without any errors.

Seems the issues are connected to the recent [predictable network interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) changes. Found users [A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824376/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-after-upgrading-to-16-04), [B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689070/network-interface-name-changes-after-update-to-15-10-udev-changes), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609676/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces), [D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758594/no-networking-failed-to-bring-up-eth0), and [E](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339016/setting-static-ip-with-predictable-network-interface) had similar symptoms. However, they had upgraded *Ubuntu* systems (without a clean install). Aditionally the proposed solutions are suggesting *disabling the assignment of fixed/predictable/unique names*. I would prefer to keep the new naming scheme/standard, eventually to find and eliminate the reason why(*?*) it is not working properly.

Found also users [F](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=134480), and [G](https://serverfault.com/questions/829230/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-on-ubuntu-16-04-01) with the same problem -- without solution.

Would be very thankful for any hint. Also, I'm happy to answer your questions if you need more in depth details.

Further you find some detailed system output.

```
$ sudo systemctl status networking.service 
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-09-04 17:21:42 IST; 1h 27min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 534 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 444 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 534 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: exiting.
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX ifup[534]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 04 17:21:42 XXX systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/setup
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

EDIT2start:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for XXX: 
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 765  bytes 523923 (511.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 803  bytes 101736 (99.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 50  bytes 3720 (3.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 50  bytes 3720 (3.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxf4f26d1b7521: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT2end.

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxf4f26d1b7521: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

EDITstart:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
...

$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

EDITend.

EDIT3start:

```
$ sudo systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-09-05 10:29:16 IST; 44min ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 565 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 438 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 565 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/networking.service

Sep 05 10:26:56 sdd9 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Sep 05 10:26:56 sdd9 ifup[565]: ifup: waiting for lock on /run/network/ifstate.enp3s0
Sep 05 10:29:16 sdd9 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

EDIT3end.

Comment: I'm confused. You say the cable connection works but the USB wifi doesn't. But your `/etc/network/interfaces` only has `eth0`, which is normally a wired connection. Where is your wifi device? Also, you get the message "ifup: failed to bring up eth0", which appears to contradict your statement that cable is working. Also, I personally just use `ifup` and `ifdown`, but I guess I'm old-fashioned.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you for your help. First I'm kinda "newbie" and understand only superficially the output. the wifi device is `wlx____` in the `$ sudo ifconfig` output. Would you need any further details -- please send me the terminal commands? See the added `$ lsusb`. Could it have any impact that I've copied the `home` folder from the old system (a similar Debian 9, but on a laptop hardware)? AFAIK the network settings are not stored inside it -- therefore the omission in the question text.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `wlx____` is **not the wireless connection** (as stated in the comment before). (Was disturbed by the "`w`" in front of the naming.) But then, what is `enp____`? I'm confused too, sorry :|

Comment: what is the output of `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: Hi. Take a look at https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Atheros_AR9271 and also https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc.  Do you have firmware-atheros installed (`apt-get install firmware-atheros`)? And the interface name is `wlan0` based on that page.

Comment: Also, what's with `lo_____`? It's just `lo`.

Comment: @GAD3R He's given the output of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes: `lo____` is `lo` (Tried to generalize/pseudomize.)

Comment: @FaheemMitha Firmware was installed. See output if I try to install it _again_  
`$ sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros`  
`Reading package lists... Done`  
`Building dependency tree`  
`Reading state information... Done`  
`firmware-atheros is already the newest version (20161130-3).`  
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: @alex Er... what?

Comment: @alex Oh, I didn't see that your file was `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup`. What on earth is that? You want a file called `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Hello :) sorry. I had not changed anything inside `/etc/network/interfaces...` it is like it was installed yesterday.

Comment: everyone: `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` is a file created by `vmdebootstrap`, which also arranges for `/etc/network/interfaces` to source it.  alex: do not obfuscate the interface names.  What they are is important to the question.

Comment: @JdeBP Thank you for your comment. Please see the interface names in the _complete_ `ifconfig` output above.

Comment: One of the dumbest failure modes I've come across in a long time. Missing interface should never keep networking stack from starting - just fail the interface gracefully. So dumb. I have a hard time thinking "experienced" software developers know what they're doing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` file then edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

(friendly edit: GAD3R suggested there should be nothing else in the file. It appears that entries can also be ignored if a line starts with # followed by a space)

Save and reboot

The `man interfaces`:

> INCLUDING OTHER FILES
>
> ```
>   Lines  beginning  with  "source" are used to include stanzas from other
>   files, so configuration can be split into many files. The word "source"
>   is  followed  by the path of file to be sourced. Shell wildcards can be
>   used.  (See wordexp(3) for details.)
> ```

In your case you are using the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` to configure the network instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`

> Lines beginning with "allow-" are  used  to  identify  interfaces  that
> should  be  brought  up automatically by various subsytems. This may be
> done using a command such as "ifup --allow=hotplug  eth0  eth1",  which
> will  only  bring up eth0 or eth1 if it is listed in an "allow-hotplug"
> line. Note that "allow-auto"  and  "auto"  are  synonyms.   (Interfaces
> marked "allow-hotplug" are brought up when udev detects them.  This can
> either be during boot if the interface is  already  present,  or  at  a
> later  time,  for  example when plugging in a USB network card.  Please
> note that this does not have anything to do with  detecting  a  network
> cable being plugged in.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Please give me a hint what "`<your_interface_here>`" is, or where I find it?

Comment: So I've tried as indirectly suggested by the text with `eth0`, rebooted, and then `eth1` and rebooted again. Non of them worked. Please see also the interface names in the question EDIT2 above. I've added the _complete_ interface names there. Please help me to find the right interface name (consider the comment of JdeBP below my question). Thank you.

Comment: Tried like told above (without removing variant, and 2X `allow-hotplug ...`). Sadly it _did not work_. The behavior changed: (1) the boot error remained, (2) the `NetworkManager` doesn't see/shows any WiFi or LAN networks anymore showing `device not managed` message for both. However the cable-LAN connection & internet works. Any idea? Did you read the comment of JdeBP below the question?

Comment: Tried as suggested, to replace `eth0` with `enp3s0` inside the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/setup` along with the changes suggested inside your answer. It doesn't work. Since I've lost too much time with this issue I consider to reinstall the whole system and prepare (a USB drive) to provide the WiFi drivers at installation time -- which I've didn't do last time. Do you think it could work?

Comment: Before reinstalling the system , Update the output of `sudo systemctl status networking.service` then we will try the old  predictable network interface names

Comment: Thank you. Added  EDIT3 as requested inside the question. Please do consider also that after the _last try, before,_ the error was not there, but the networking service did start very slowly -- a timer started counting more then a minute, while after booting the `NetworkManager` was again stating `device not managed` for cable and WiFi. The **networking service in working now**, however the WiFi doesen't work. Could it be that there are two distinct issues I have: (1) `networking service` isn't starting properly at boot-time, (2) `WiFi` not working with right with the `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Delete everything from your `interfaces` configuration file , just keep `auto lo` and `iface lo inet loopback` then reboot

Comment: **OK**: `networking.service` is working fine and the `NetworkManger` _too_ (meaning it is showing the connections and not `device not managed` as before). However the WiFi is not conecting -- even if it is showing the networks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort! Please adapt your answer to the concluding remark "Delete everything from your interfaces...". I will then check the answer as the solution. Seems I have to research further for the WiFi issues. If you have something in mind what could help me send me a short comment. Have a good day! :)

Comment: Sorry, had to reinstall the whole system. WiFi still doesn't work. But, at least, after by removing the `.../setup` file and following your solution the error doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: Can I avoid reboot?

Answer (score 6):

Just putting a `#` in front of source `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*` in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, so it doesn't reference the `/interfaces.d/setup` file solved it for me. Everything working fine. The solution is kinda logical.

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score -2):

Worked for me for Wlan!

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

then change,

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet static
```

to

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: The default setting on your interfaces configuration file for the `lo` is `iface lo inet loopback`