# Startup Debian 9 fails with: `Failed to start Raise network interfaces` after motherboard replacement

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I have the same symptoms as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390307/startup-debian-9-error-failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces) but slightly different configuration. My Debian server is standing in a Datacenter so I have no local access but only remote access.

Since the motherboard was replaced, I cannot access my server in any way unless I get into rescue mode. Here I can mount the disk drives and examine the files.

So, the **boot.log** shows me

```
...
[FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.
...
```

I'm not sure what is the problem and how to actually find the root cause of the problem, so here I post some config files. These should be the same as before the motherboard replacement, as I did not change them

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#
# device: eth0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address  vvv.www.xxx.zzz
    netmask  255.255.255.224
    gateway  vvv.www.xxx.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address  xxxx:xxx:xxx:xxxx::x
    netmask  128
    gateway  xxxx::1
    up sysctl -p

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  10.10.10.2
    netmask  255.255.255.0
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**/etc/default/networking**

```
# Configuration for networking init script being run during
# the boot sequence

# Set to 'no' to skip interfaces configuration on boot
#CONFIGURE_INTERFACES=yes

# Don't configure these interfaces. Shell wildcards supported/
#EXCLUDE_INTERFACES=

# Set to 'yes' to enable additional verbosity
#VERBOSE=no
```

**/etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service**

Any clue where to start to look at?

```
[Unit]
Description=Raise network interfaces
Documentation=man:interfaces(5)
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network.target
After=local-fs.target network-pre.target apparmor.service systemd-sysctl.service systemd-modules-load.service
Before=network.target shutdown.target network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/networking
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sh -c '[ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle'
ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment
ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStartSec=5min
```

---

**Update 1**

```
root@chroot > ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xx.xx.xx/xx brd xx.xx.xx.xx scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx::x/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules**

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x1502 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="4c:72:b9:98:12:ab", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: have you checked this ...https://askubuntu.com/questions/824376/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-after-upgrading-to-16-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` or modify it to match your new ethernet interface, which is named eth1 now.

Comment: Thanks @Ipor Sircer, this was it. I had some wrong understanding but after reading [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) it helped me understand better.